# Integrity Error after registration in registration redux for Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using,

**Django==1.8
django-registration-redux==1.1**

After submitting the registration form I am getting the Integrity Error .

I am actually following a tutorial.

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
NOT NULL constraint failed: registration_registrationprofile.activated
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: registration_registrationprofile.activated
Exception Location: /home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  /home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.0
Python Path:    
['/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/automation',
 '/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 12 Apr 2016 12:14:10 +0000
```

please check the traceback below

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'API')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/registration/views.py" in dispatch
  79.         return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/registration/views.py" in post
  35.             return self.form_valid(request, form)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/registration/views.py" in form_valid
  82.         new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/registration/backends/default/views.py" in register
  92.             request=request,
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/registration/models.py" in create_inactive_user
  91.         registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/registration/models.py" in create_profile
  115.                            activation_key=activation_key)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  348.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  710.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  738.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  822.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  861.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  963.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  658.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/bhanu_prakash/Desktop/ENV1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  318.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: registration_registrationprofile.activated
```

Probably some db issue.

models code for reference

```
class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):

    ACTIVATED = "ALREADY_ACTIVATED"

    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModelString(),unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'))
    activation_key = models.CharField(_('activation key'), max_length=40)

    objects = RegistrationManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('registration profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('registration profiles')

    def __str__(self):
        ...
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to tell what the problem is. Which tutorial are you following? The latest version of django-registration-redux is 1.4. You could try upgrading, to see if it's a bug with 1.1.

Comment: @Alasdair Django from scratch by stone river.. redux versions above 1.1 need base.html to be there in the templates. I am not using them now, (as per the tutorial). I am a newbie to django and also webdev. What code you want me to paste? views, forms?

Comment: Ideally you want to paste enough code so that others can recreate the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: EDIT: code for your reference




class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
 
    ACTIVATED = "ALREADY_ACTIVATED"

    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModelString(), unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'))
    activation_key = models.CharField(_('activation key'), max_length=40)

    objects = RegistrationManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('registration profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('registration profiles')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Registration information for %s" % self.user

    def activation_key_expired(self):

Comment: That's not enough code ... it's not clear why that model would cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete db.sqlite3 and then run `./manage.py migrate` again. You are using `django-registration-redux==1.1` and tables were created with 1.2.